# for loop not looping over entire array

Tags: google-apps-script

Can someone please explain why the below for loop isn't looping over the entire array? I've run this exact script before and it works fine, I just can't figure out what I'm missing here.

The source Data looks like this. There are 15 rows of data in the sample set I'm working from excluding the headers

| Start | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| 14/08/2020 12:21:33 | 00:00:06 |
| 14/08/2020 12:21:56 |  |
| 14/08/2020 15:39:12 | 00:10:49 |
| 14/08/2020 16:11:10 |  |
| 14/08/2020 16:11:33 | 00:16:03 |

The script I have is

```
function time() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();

  //console.log(values)
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var st = values[i][1];
    var s = st.split(':');
    var res = (+s[0]) * 3600 + (+s[1]) * 60 + (+s[2]);
  }

console.log(res)
}
```

If I log out `res` I get a single value instead of all 15

```
Execution log
12:06:25 AM Notice  Execution started
12:06:28 AM Info    475
12:06:27 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Because the log part is outside the loop

Comment: Of course yes. I knew I was missing something here. Thanks @ TheMaster. That would be the reason yes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
function test() {
  let st='00:10:49';
  let s=st.split(':');
  var res = ++s[0] * 3600 + ++s[1] * 60 + ++s[2];
  Logger.log(res);//4310
}
```

Try it this way:

```
function time() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  let o = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var st = values[i][1];
    var s = st.split(':');
    var res = ++s[0] * 3600 + ++s[1] * 60 + ++s[2];
    o.push(res);
  }
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(o.filter(v=>!isNaN(v)).join('<br />')), 'Numbers only Please');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. Your solution definitely works. Not a direct answer to my original question but does what I originally intended to do.